# spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix compatible version for Spring boot 2.7.9

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I'm using **spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.9** .

According to the Spring cloud release compatibility matrix , the version of spring cloud that is compatible with this version is **2021.0.3**

**2021.0.x aka Jubilee  2.6.x, 2.7.x (Starting with 2021.0.3)**

[Source](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)

Based on this I'm assuming that the dependency version for hystrix that I need to use is **2.1.3.RELEASE**. I'm assuming **2021.0.3==2.1.3**.

However I've tried every version of Spring Cloud Starter Netflix Hystrix from **2.2.10.RELEASE** to  **2.1.3.RELEASE** but I keep getting `the Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata` Exception

Any idea what I'm doing wrong

---

Comment: I finally concluded that hystrix is incompatible with my version of Spring boot. I ended up using Spring Retry.